PostGreSQL and Spring Boot R2DBC - keep getting Cannot decode value of type long with OID 20
I keep getting this error:

PostGreSQL (16.4) and
Spring Boot R2DBC (1.0.5.RELEASE)  - reactive
relational database connectivity support from Spring Boot

.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot decode value of type long with OID 20

My code:
@Repository
class StudentExtendedRepositoryImpl(
    private val databaseClient: DatabaseClient
) : StudentExtendedRepository {

    override fun findAllByFirstnameContainingIgnoreCase(firstname: String?): Flow<Student> {
        val query = databaseClient
            .sql("SELECT * FROM student WHERE firstname ILIKE :firstname")
            .bind("firstname", "%$firstname%")
            .map { row ->
                Student(
                    row.get("id", Long::class.java),
                    row.get("firstname", String::class.java) ?: "",
                    row.get("lastname", String::class.java) ?: "",
                    row.get("age", Int::class.java) ?: 0
                )
            }.all()
            .asFlow()

        return query
    }

}

My flyway setup:
CREATE TABLE student(
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR (100),
    lastname VARCHAR (20),
    age integer
);

Whats going on?
Is there a more sophisticated SQL Query library I can use for Spring R2DBC, instead of having to write custom SQL Querties in the above form?
UPDATE
This fixed it. Not sure why, as I thought java and javaObjectType are the same
   Student(
                row.get("id", Long::class.javaObjectType),
                row.get("firstname", String::class.javaObjectType) ?: "",
                row.get("lastname", String::class.javaObjectType) ?: "",
                row.get("age", Int::class.javaObjectType) ?: 0
            )


To question text add:  1) Postgres version. 2) JDBC driver source and version.

I have updated the text


Per request add to question text, not title. 2) I have no idea what  Spring R2DBC is, but I'm betting it is having issue with long <--> int8 conversion.


Sorry. Re-updated
